# CvConnectedComp.contour is NULL with cvFloodFill

Tags: c, opencv, flood-fill, connected-components

I am trying to use `CvConnectedComp` which is an output from `cvFloodFill`.

```
CvConnectedComp comp;
cvFloodFill(imgInput,seedPoint,
        cvScalarAll(0),cvScalarAll(.1),cvScalarAll(1.),
        &comp,CV_FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY,imgMask);
```

I am able to use `comp.rect` for drawing the component, but `comp.contour` is `NULL`.I want to use it for further processing. I tried without mask also, but still it is same result.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: you **must not** use opencv's deprecated c-api, it's only around for legacy/maintenance reasons. no new code should be written using that..

Comment: @berak I am using this for maintenance reason of my work. Kindly comment on the problem

Comment: again, the only valid advice is to rewrite the whole thing using c++

Comment: again, kindly comment on the problem.

Comment: @berak and sonu: this is a recent discussion on Meta: [where does SO stand on answers versus alternatives?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296613/2564301). Comment from Hans Passant: "SO is not a personal helpdesk, the Q+A needs to be useful to more than one programmer and that includes the consideration for alternatives".

Answer (score 2):

Note: The deprecated OpenCV C API should only be used for the support of legacy code. New code should use the C++ API.

Looking at the code for OpenCV 3.0.0, `cvFloodFill` does not populate `comp.contour`; the only members it sets are `.rect`, `.area`, and `.value`. I don't know if it was always this way, but here's what's happening:

First, look at the signature for the C++ [`cv::floodFill`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#floodfill):

```
int floodFill(InputOutputArray image, InputOutputArray mask, Point seedPoint, 
              Scalar newVal, Rect* rect=0, Scalar loDiff=Scalar(), 
              Scalar upDiff=Scalar(), int flags=4 )
```

Notice that there is no connected component structure here, only a `Rect`. The return value is the area of the region that is floodfilled.

This is the method that is called by `cvFloodFill`. The code passes `&comp->rect` to the C++ method where it is populated, uses the return value for `comp->area` an copies `newVal` into `comp->value`.